# Name for words created from mispronunciations?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Is there a name for the process by which words are created out of mispronunciations of other words, or for the words themselves?

Examples that come to mind include *ain't* for *isn't* and *prolly* for *probably*.

I suppose these words would be called *slang* words, but they're a particular kind of slang that comes from the original words being more difficult (or just taking longer) to say.

Also, is this the same phenomenon that gives us more casual, abbreviated versions of longer words, like *comfy* for *comfortable* or even *ˈkazh* for *casual*?

Comment: FWIW, *ain't* derived from *amn't* and *aren't*, not from *isn't*

Comment: @nohat Thanks, I didn't know that. *am not*, *are not*, *is not*... all forms of *to be*, or, *not to be*. ;-)

Comment: I've never seen (heard?) *kazh* for *casual*, but other common ones are *soz* for *sorry*, and *pacific* for *specific*. I don't think they're really "mispronunciations", so much as spoken/txt casual/slang *shortenings*, as @cornbread ninja says.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's the only way that I can think of to spell the way it sounds -- essentially the first syllable of *casual*. I have to admit that I haven't seen it either -- but this process of spoken words being written down and growing into part of the language is what I was thinking about.

Answer (score 4):

They're *[clippings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28morphology%29)*. Stan Carey has a post on the topic [here](http://stancarey.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/ledgebag-is-totes-amaze/).

Comment: Of the OP’s examples, only *cazh* is a clipping, but +1 anyway.

Comment: From the link, the 'clippings' look like just the first syllable(s) of a much longer word. So I wouldn't think of them as mispronunciations, just abbreviations.

Answer (score 4):

Two remotely-related problems are

- *[mondegreen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mondegreen)*, "A form of error arising from mishearing a spoken or sung phrase" or "A misunderstanding of a written or spoken phrase as a result of multiple definitions."  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen) comments, "If a person stubbornly sticks to a mispronunciation after being corrected, the error is known as a mumpsimus."
- *[eggcorn](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eggcorn)*, "
  An idiosyncratic but semantically motivated substitution of a word or phrase for a word or words that sound identical, or nearly so, at least in the dialect the speaker uses."

*Edit:* Jon Purdy has already mentioned the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) and two mechanisms for changes in pronunciation: [cluster reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_reduction) and [vowel reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction_in_English).  At a slightly higher level, creation of words from others via mispronunciations ought to be an important part of *language evolution* and figuratively one ought to be able to call the process *[morphogenesis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/morphogenesis)*, which is a word from biology that refers to "differentiation of tissues and subsequent growth of structures in an organism".  But no, "language evolution" instead refers to [evolutionary linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_evolution), which apparently concentrates on relations between human evolution and development of language ability, rather than on changes in specific languages.

Comment: Mondegreens arise from mis-hearings, not mispronunciations.  The error is on the listener's side, not the speaker's so ... related, but not it.  Eggcorn is pretty good, though.

Comment: @Boofus, certainly the listener is misperceiving, but often as a consequence of poor enunciation on speaker's part.  Also, I refer to mondegreens and eggcorns as "remotely-related" to question.

Answer (score 2):

*[Ain't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ain%27t) for isn't* is a colloquialism.

> prolly for probably

and

> comfy for comfortable

are informal shortenings of each, but I don't believe there is a term for this phenomenon aside from *informal shortening* or *slang*.

Comment: Errr shouldn't that be "colloquial*ism*"?

Comment: oof.  yes, or without the 'a'.  edited.

Answer (score 2):

Your question needs to be unasked a bit. *Ain’t* isn’t a mispronunciation of *isn’t*; it was originally a contraction of *am not* that was then generalised to all the negative forms of *to be*.

*Prolly* and its rarer cousin *probby* are derived from *probably* by **phonological reduction**, the process by which words lose phonetic complexity through omission, approximation, and transposition of sounds. By the same process, *comfortable* is usually pronounced *comfterble*, which can be abbreviated and diminuted into *comfy*.

Different kinds of reduction include [cluster reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_reduction) (*knife→nife*) and [vowel reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_reduction_in_English) (*and→n*).

This is one of the major reasons that the pronunciations of English words can stray so far from their written form—*walked* used to be pronounced as it is written, *wall-ked*, rather than the *woct* form we hear nowadays.

Unrelated to your question, the other major reason for the state of English spelling is a drastic change in English vowel pronunciation called the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) that occurred between about 1350 and 1500. The pronunciation changed, but the spelling didn’t.